# Помогите создать функцию repeat(str, n), кот-я возвращает строку, состоящую из n повторений строки str. n по умол-ю 2, str — пустая строка

Tags: javascript, функции

```
function repeat(str, n = 2) {
    return str.repeat(n);
}

console.log(repeat('')); // должен вывести 2-е пустые строки
console.log(repeat('', 4)); // должен вывести 4 пустые строки
```

Comment: Проблема в чём?

Comment: шо за бред 4 пустые строки? Как это ты представляешь?

Comment: это д/з я сам не понимаю что делать :( надо вывести  2-е пустые строки по умолчанию) а если передать в параметр функции допустим 4 то строк должно быть выведено 4)

Comment: по любому 4 пустые строки это пустая строка, так что вы можете предъявить что вывели именно 2, 3, 1000 пустыx строк предварительно доказав что ''+ '' === ''

Comment: это как сумма 10 или 20 нулей все равно нуль. А нуль в свою очередь сумма 10 или 20 нулей

Comment: И вообще, использовать готовую функцию для решения задачи - читерство!)

Comment: одним словом в консоли разработчика должно вывести 2 пустые строчки,

Comment: а в другом случае 4

Comment: `return new Array(n).fill(str).join("\n") + "\n";` ?) Все повторения - на новой строке, для пустой строки - только переносы строк. При этом, это не одно и то же, что repeat.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME да если подходить именно с точки зрения строчки (row), а не строки (string) Только в задании строки. Вот сидишь и понимаешь сколько смысла в словах

Comment: :) да похоже то самое! но вот я только начинающий, а у тебя код навороченный (если честно я его не понима :( можешь в двух словах объяснить что ты сделал)

Comment: @AzizUmarov "4 пустые строки? Как это ты представляешь?" - Программа должна нарисовать шесть прозрачных линий.

Comment: 7 красных взаимно перпендикулярных линий :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код работает как надо.

4 пустые строки `''` это пустая строка `''`, и другого быть не может

```js
console.log(('' + '' + '' + '') === '') // true
```

либо как предложил идею @OPTIMUSPRIME, дублировать строчки

```js
function repeat(str, n = 2) {
    return new Array(n).fill(str).join("\n");
}

console.log('beging');
console.log(repeat('')); // должен вывести 2-е пустые строки
console.log('end');
console.log('beging');
console.log(repeat('', 4)); // должен вывести 4 пустые строки
console.log('end');
```

где `new Array(n)` - создание массива из n элементов

```
fill(str) - заполнение массива с str
join("\n") - объединение массива с разделителем "\n"
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

```
function repeat(str, n = 2) {
    if (!str) {
      return " ".repeat(n);
    } else {
      return str.repeat(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: " " это не пустая строка

Comment: не знаю что имел автор ввиду, по поводу пустой строки (является ли пробел ей). Уберите if-else для улучшения кода =) `return !str ? " ".repeat(n) : str.repeat(n);`

Comment: @DmitriiSedov явное же лучше, чем неявное :) тернарник читается хуже, а автор вопроса очевидно еще не искушенный программист

Comment: в любом случае подменять ожидаемый ответ не хорошо

Comment: @SergeyLukashev ну я просто предложил)) но раз тут Д/З как автор написал, то Ваш вариант будет ближе!